# Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable' error while return from subscribe

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
    setPrivileges(privilege: string): Observable<boolean> {
        if (this.loginService.privilegeList != null && this.loginService.privilegeList != undefined && this.loginService.privilegeList.getValue() != null) {
            this.privileges = this.loginService.privilegeList.getValue().filter(item => item.name === privilege);
            console.log("if this.privileges : "+this.privileges);
                return Observable.of(true);
        } else {
              return this.getUserRolesAndMenus().subscribe((result: any) => {  // line 7
               console.log("result  :"+JSON.stringify(result));
               this.privileges = result.roles.filter((element: any) => {
                    element.privileges.filter((item: any) => {
                        item.name === privilege;
                    })
                })
                console.log("esle this.privileges : "+this.privileges);
                if(this.privileges == null)
                    return Observable.of(true);
                else
                       return Observable.of(true);
            });
        }
    }
```

On line 7 it throws exception as

[ts]

Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
(method) UserService.getUserRolesAndMenus(): Observable
To get the user details.
'

What is doing wrong here ?

```
/**
     * To get the user details.
     */
    getUserRolesAndMenus(): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append(AppUtils.HEADER_AUTHENTICATION, localStorage.getItem(AppUtils.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN));
        return this.http.get(AppUtils.GET_USER_ROLES_AND_MENUS + AppUtils.SYSTEM_ID_IRS, { headers: headers })
            .map(response => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError)
           /* .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();*/
    }
```

Comment: It this: `return this.getUserRolesAndMenus().subscribe`. The [`subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/Observable.ts#L74-L76) method does not return an `Observable`; it returns a [`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html).

Comment: this.getUserRolesAndMenus(), it returns an observable. updated the question added getUserRolesAndMenus() code.

Comment: @cartant : How can I fix this, need to return observable boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a subscription instead of a Observable. Change `subscribe` to `switchMap`. This will return an Observable and replaces the result of `getUserRolesAndMenus` by the Observable you create with `Observable.of(...)`